# Creating a series of regressions with loop in R

Tags: r, loops, regression, economics

I'm trying to create 301 regressions and save their residuals to a dataframe with a loop. The regressions have the state gdp by industry on the left and needs to have the corresponding US gdp on the right. They are in the same order within the data frame, so hopefully that makes things easier.

The problem is that it's regressing each column with each other column resulting in over 10,000 regressions instead of 301. Hopefully someone more loop savy than me can help figure this out. And detailed explanations would be incredibly helpful, I've never had to loop in R before. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
# Create start and end vectors
WY_start = 2
WY_end = 302
US_start = 303
US_end = 604
res <- data.frame(combined_gdp$Year)
# Loop
for (i in WY_start:WY_end) {
    WY = colnames(combined_gdp)[i]
    for (j in US_start:US_end) {
        US = colnames(combined_gdp)[j]
        model <- lm(get(WY) ~ get(US) + COAL_vol + OILW_vol + NGS_vol, 
                    na.action = na.exclude, data=combined_gdp)
        cbind(res, resid(model))
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Could you have a look at creating a reproducible example? Even a sample of data for two states would allow someone to attempt to get your code working.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Help us help you by posting a reproducible example. It does not have to be the very same data you are using just some dummy data.frame might do. I suggest this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It might be more difficult and take longer to ask question but you will learn quite a bit about your current question by doing so. Regarding your question I think you have one loop too many.

Answer (score 0):

Not having the the data to test with it is hard to give a complete answer, however I think the issue you are having is caused by an extra loop.

```
WY_start <-2
WY_end   <-302
US_start <-303
US_end   <-604
res      <-data.frame(combined_gdp$Year)

# Loop
for (i in WY_start:WY_end){
     WY <- colnames(combined_gdp)[i]
     US <- colnames(combined_gdp)[i+301]
     model <- lm(get(WY)~get(US)+COAL_vol+OILW_vol+NGS_vol, 
           na.action=na.exclude,data=combined_gdp)
     cbind(res,resid(model))
}
```

Your code is taking each [ i ] and comparing them to each [ j ] so you are getting i * j comparisons. Since they are in the same order you only need 1 index. This code will take column 2,3...302 and compare them to column 303,304...604 respectively. I would also recommend storing your `cbind(res,resid(model))` into a list.